# PHP Variable inside .attr String

Tags: php

I can't figure the syntax of placing a php variable inside a string. Code is as follows:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       jQuery('#pinfo').attr('href','mailto:mobile@domain.com?subject=' .  get_the_title() );
        jQuery('#pinfo').attr('class','pullup');
  };
```

`get_the_title()` is not being displayed and the code seems to break with my current syntax.

Comment: You should set the variable and then you can use it in the html. Can you post the code for get_the_title()?

Comment: get_the_title() is a standard wordpress function - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: I didn't see tag wordpress, i can't read minds sorry.

Comment: i didn't think it would be a wordpress problem - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use PHP alongside javascript, PHP gets executed before the javascript does. So simply write your code like so:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       jQuery('#pinfo').attr('href','mailto:mobile@domain.com?subject=<?=get_the_title()?>');
        jQuery('#pinfo').attr('class','pullup');
  };
```

Once the browser renders the page, it will leave you with javascript that looks something like this (which is exactly what the browser needs):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       jQuery('#pinfo').attr('href','mailto:mobile@domain.com?subject=My Page Title');
        jQuery('#pinfo').attr('class','pullup');
  };
```

Comment: Thank you ! you are a star x

Comment: on a separate note this code only works on the first element with the id '#pinfo' - if I have 2 elements with the id '#pinfo' on the same page, the second element is ignored. Not sure if this is how things are supposed to work..

Comment: Watch out when using PHP short open tags, though: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: @JoannaMikalai My pleasure :) That is happening because when you use an id selector (e.g. #my-name) you are only targeting one element. Try using a class name instead (e.g. .pinfo) and add that class to both of the elements. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tE7f9/